# JS cannot parse JSON with unicode character

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string `{"name":""C\u008cUR Carmen"}` but `\u008c` is not parsed. It shows empty character instead.

```
json = '{"name":"C\u008cUR Carmen"}';
json = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```

Show : `CUR Carmen`

Expect : `CŒUR Carmen`

Please help.

*** Note *** : The JSON data is returned by the PHP server so there shouldn't be any syntax error because I used `json_encode` and get the response from AJAX. It works with other characters such as `à, é` but only this wierd character doesn't display properly

**EDIT** : **Solved**! It's not a JS problem it's a charset problem returned by MySQL. You can use `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` before returning SQL data. Show `\u0152` as expected

Comment: There is also an extra double-quote in your json string.

Comment: Please read my edits

Comment: In my FF console expression `JSON.parse('{"name":"C\u008cUR Carmen"}')` is evaluated correctly and unicode character is present in output, maybe there is some problems with font used to output this string.

Comment: The code you've posted does work properly. How are you "showing" the resulting value?

Comment: Also the Unicode character `008C` is **not** `Œ`. It's a control character. To get that character, you'd want `\u0152` instead. [Here is a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/36mwnuqw/)

Comment: @Pointy you are correct. Do you know why php `json_encode` output a control character instead of unicode character? If you do how to resolve this please post an answer so I can give you point

Comment: No, I have no idea, unless the PHP code is running with the wrong encoding scheme.

Comment: @ThanhTrung As mentioned before, I assume that you have some transcoding-errors in your php-code before you use `json_encode`. You could try using `utf8_encode` before encoding to json

Comment: There is no transcoding error because it works for other unicode characters such as `à, é`

Comment: @VitaliyG evaluated without error doesn't mean it displays properly

Comment: @ThanhTrung I edited my answer and added a fiddle on how to revert the escaped unicode character with javascript

Comment: @ThanhTrung If you use PHP 5.4+ you can use the `json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: @ThanhTrung Yes my point exactly, title of this question implies there is some problem with JSON parsing, but the problem is in something completely different

Comment: @VitalilyG since Pointy pointed it out, there's probably a problem with the server side which encode Œ into \u008. I guess I got to solve it from here

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to escape an unicode character stated in [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> **2.5.  Strings**
>
> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
>   family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
>      quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
>      quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
>      quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
>      through U+001F).

You can use your unicode string directly:

```
json = '{"name":"CŒUR Carmen"}';
json = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```

I think there's a transcoding bug in your server side implementation where you change the output to ASCII before using `json_encode`. It is a requirement of JSON that all data is encoded in Unicode.

**Edit**

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/131dq8h0/) there's an example how to revert the escaped unicode in javascript.

Comment: And if he/she can't change the json output ?

Comment: @Magicprog.fr Then he has to transcode the string first.

Comment: He* . I can do a `.replace` but not a good way because we can't know all possible unicode character

Comment: @TanhTrung You could use `String.fromCharCode()` and match the number after `\u` using regex to turn it back to unicode

Comment: @ThanhTrung You still have the unescaped `"` in it in this case. Do you have influence on the serverside implementation?

Comment: @ThanhTrung see my comment - `\u008c` is not the `Œ` character.

Comment: @ThanhTrung But do you have influence on the server side implementation? If you do please check the encoding of the string before you use `json_encode`

Comment: I can influence server side. But I don't think the charset is the problem. The problem probably comes from the function `json_encode`

Comment: Hehe, still not work. You can check it in Chrome console

Comment: @ThanhTrung When you replace the `\u008c` with a legit escaped unicode character like `\u0152` it works :-) [check this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/131dq8h0/1/)

Comment: Im just saying that your fiddle doesn't work. Of course it works if it's `\u0152` but how to convert `\u008c` to `\u0152` ?

Comment: There's no such possibility because there is something wrong in the conversion in php but I'm still trying to figuring out. Do you get the string from a text file?

Comment: Alright, the original text is ... `CŒUR Carmen` then it is encoded into utf-8 so that json_encode(...) works properly. But... only letter `Œ` doesn't work whereas `è,à,ë...` (everything you can type with a keyboard) works properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81315/discussion-between-berkyl-and-thanh-trung).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `"` and escape the `\`:

```
json = '{"name":""C\u008cUR Carmen"}';
```

should be

```
json = '{"name":"\\"C\\u008cUR Carmen"}';
```

If the 4th `"` is just a typing an error, just escape the `\` that:

```
json = '{"name":"C\\u008cUR Carmen"}';
```

Comment: I think that extra double-quote is a typo, so you should probably take it out.

Comment: There is no need to escape the character